# How do I create an orthographic camera that correctly scales my sprites/textures with libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm creating a game with libgdx that I want to run at a higher resolution on the desktop, but I want it to scale everything down correctly when I run it on android at smaller resolutions. I've read that the best way to do this is to not use a pixel perfect camera, and instead to use world coordinates, but I'm not sure how to correctly do that.

This is the code I have right now:

```
@Override
public void create() {
    characterTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("character.png"));
    characterTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(characterTexture, 0, 0,  100, 150);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();


    Gdx.gl10.glClearColor(0.4f, 0.6f, 0.9f, 1);

    float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    camera= new OrthographicCamera(aspectRatio, 1.0f);

}

@Override
public void render() {
    GL10 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL10();

    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    camera.apply(gl);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    draw();
}

private void draw() {
    //batch.getProjectionMatrix().set(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();

    batch.draw(characterTextureRegion, 0, 0, // the bottom left corner of the box, unrotated
            1f, 1f, // the rotation center relative to the bottom left corner of the box
            0.390625f, 0.5859375f, // the width and height of the box
            1, 1, // the scale on the x- and y-axis
            0); // the rotation angle


    batch.end();
}
```

The texture I'm use is 256x256 with the actual image in it being 100x150.

This is the result I get when I run the game: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9T7o.png

The sprite that gets rendered is massive, considering this is the original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E0fh.png

What's the best way to go about making it so that the sprites get rendered at their original size while still keeping the ability to have the game scale correctly when played in different resolutions?

I've only found two solutions,  both of which I don't like.

1. The image showed up how it was supposed to if I used pixel coordinates for the camera, but then that didn't scale at all when I put it on my phone with a different resolution.
2. I can scale the texture region down when I draw it, but it seems like there is a better way because it is extremely tedious trying to figure out the correct number to scale it by.

Comment: Try using the FitViewport class

Answer (score 4):

Have you ever used the Libgdx setup tool? When you create a project with it, it has a sample image that is displayed. It seems to keep it's ratio correct no matter what size you change the screen to.

```
public class RotationTest implements ApplicationListener {
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture texture;
private Sprite sprite;
Stage stage;
public boolean leonAiming = true;

@Override
public void create() {      
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 512, 275);

    sprite = new Sprite(region);
    sprite.setSize(0.9f, 0.9f * sprite.getHeight() / sprite.getWidth());
    sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
    sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2, -sprite.getHeight()/2);   }....

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
```

Comment: HAHA, just saw that this is from 2011, guess you've found an answer by now, or stopped developing

Comment: I've tried this implementation but it's not drawing my textures. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to fix boundaries to the world (I mean to your game ). In that world only you actors(game characters) should play. If you are crossing boundaries, manage it with camera like showing up, down, left and right.